# Regex (?U)\p{Punct} is missing some Unicode punctuation signs in Java

Tags: java, regex, unicode

First of all, I want to remove all punctuation signs in a String. I wrote the following code.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{Punct}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~（hello）");
if (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll(""));
```

After replacement I got this output: `（hello）`.

So the pattern matches the one of `!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~`, which matches the [official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

But I want to remove "（" `Fullwidth Left Parenthesis U+FF08*` and "）" `Fullwidth Right Parenthesis U+FF09` as well, so I changed my code to this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?U)\\p{Punct}");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~（）");
        if (matcher.find())
            System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll(""));
```

After replacement, I got this output: `$+<=>^`|~`

It indeed matched "（" `Fullwidth Left Parenthesis U+FF08*` and "）" `Fullwidth Right Parenthesis U+FF09`, bit it missed `$+<=>^`|~`.

I am so confused. Why did that happen? Can anyone give some help?

Comment: Consider using [`[^\p{Alnum}\s]`](https://regex101.com/r/rmwUFq/1) for targeting all [characters that are neither](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) alphanumeric nor whitespace.

Comment: @bobble bubble i want to match all punctuation in a String contains Unicode Characters like "你好".Using that pattern will result in matching non-punctuation characters.

Comment: So you want to leave unicode letters+digits and emojis? I tried [`[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{Cs}\p{So}\s]+`](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyypr5ay8d) though I'm not sure how far this is supported in Java. It does not work in Regex101's Java-mode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unicode (that is when you use `(?U)`) and POSIX (when not using `(?U)`) disagrees on what counts as a punctuation.

When you don't use `(?U)`, `\p{Punct}` matches the [POSIX punctuation character class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#posix), which is just

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

When you use `(?U)`, `\p{Punct}` matches the [Unicode Punctuation category](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category), which does not include some of the characters in the above list, namely:

```
$+<=>^`|~
```

For example, the Unicode category for `$` is "Symbol, Currency", or Sc. See [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0024/index.htm).

If you want to match $+<=>^`|~, plus all the Unicode punctuations, you can put them both in a character class. You can also just directly use the Unicode category "P", rather than turning on Unicode mode with `(?U)`.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\p{P}$+<=>^`|~]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~（）");
// you don't need "find" first
System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll(""));
```